# Why is my fread fwrite program not copying the first character over in C?

Tags: c, malloc, fwrite, fread

Help with using Malloc / freads /fwrites?? The first letter isn't copying over?

```
   while((c = getc(in))!=EOF){
      fread(point, length, 1, in);  
      fwrite(point, length, 1, final); 
   }
```

Comment: Note: Best not to `fwrite(point...` without first checking the result of `fread(point ...`

Answer (score 3):

`getc` reads a character into `c`. So the first character will be stored into `c`, and the next one will be the second character.

Then `fread` reads a bunch of characters (`count` of them) into the memory pointed to by `ptr`. So the second, third, ..., count+1'th characters will be stored into that memory.

Then `fwrite` writes them (of course).

(Then your program repeats this until it gets to the end of the file)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input from file and output to file works correctly, here is some problem with the code chunk you provided:

- You declared `ptr` as `(int*)malloc(count)`. The problem is, `ptr` here is treated as an array of integers, which means each element has the size of 4 bytes instead of 1, so `count` must be a multiple of 4. If you want to use `ptr` to store char symbols, change it to `ptr = (char*)malloc(count)`, or `ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * count)` if your 'symbols' are actually 4 byte integers;
- You read characters to the variable `c`, but you're not using it.
- According to [`this description`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), the second parameter of `fread` and `fwrite` are the size of your elements, and the third is the number of elements you want to read/write.
- If you want to do `fread` until end of file, there's no need to do `while ((c=getc(in)) != EOF)...`, just follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697783/how-does-fread-know-when-the-file-is-over-in-c)

Hope this helps.